# Why does Avatar Mask not work as expected?

Tags: unity, animation-controller, avatar

I have 2 layers: The base layer, and an upper body layer.
On the upper body layer, I have an avatar mask because I only want to affect the upper body.
However, this mask doesn't work as expected.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what is looks like when the upper body layer has a weight of 0:

[image]

And this is with the upper body layer with a weight of 1 and with the Avatar Mask:

[image]

As one can see, the lower body is affected. The avatar mask doesn't seem to have an effect.
Is that a bug in Unity, or is there anything I could still check?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get a different result if you exclude the hips from your mask?

Comment: @DMGregory How would I exclude the hips? The avatar mask offers 1) Humanoid and 2) Transform. You're asking about 2), right?

Comment: My model's rig is set to Generic, and I'm using a Humanoid avatar mask. I guess that is the problem.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, your comment has led me onto the right track. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had defined my model's rig as "Generic".

In this case, the "Humanoid" type avatar mask may not be used.

According to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/class-AvatarMask.html), in this case, the "Transform" avatar mask type has to be used.

Once I used the "Transform" avatar mask type, it worked as expected.